# Ensure User Entered Integer

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-forms, django-templates

I am new to Django, and I recently created a system where users can look up a record based on a number.  It's just a simple search.  The system numbers have leading zeros, and I want the system to recognize the numbers with or without the zeros.  I have been able to implement this system and I am converting the number the user specifies with the following code:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(SearchResultsView, self).get_queryset()
    search_query = int(self.request.GET.get("q"))
    if search_query:
        queryset = Book.objects.filter(Q(request_number__icontains=search_query)).distinct()
```

The code above works fine, as long as the user enters a number.  If they typo and include letters, I get invalid literal for Base10.  I understand the error, a letter is not an INT.  I have spent most of the afternoon looking for how to prevent this error and I can't find what I'm looking for. I have tried to do something like:

```
    if search_query:
        try:
            queryset = Book.objects.filter(Q(request_number__icontains=search_query)).distinct()
        except ValueError:
            q = 0000000
    return queryset
```

But the letters are still interpreted and then I receive the invalid literal for Base10 error again.  How can I prevent the letters from causing a problem with my query based on a number?

I have also figured out that if I remove the conversion to INT for the search query, the letters no longer cause a problem and the system returns nothing as I would expect it to so I have a work around.  Just wondering how I could get the system to do both, accept the letters and also then prevent the invalid literal error and allow the system to turn the input into integers.  Thanks in advance for your helpful suggestions.

As Daniel Roseman suggested, I tried to use the following form, but it doesn't seem to catch the error either...

class RequestNumberSearch(forms.Form):

```
q = forms.IntegerField(required=True)

def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super(RequestNumberSearch, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['q'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'name2'

def clean_q(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['q']
    if q != int:  
        raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter valid numbers!")

    return data
```

Comment: This is exactly what forms are for.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman..Yes I tried to leverage a form for this purpose as well...I added the form and it still doesn't seem to work....

Comment: But if you want it to validate that the value is an integer, why don't you use an IntegerField rather than a CharField?

Comment: Changing the form to IntegerField gave me what I was looking for.  Thanks Daniel Roseman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to cast the query to int before checking it.

```
search_query = self.request.GET.get("q")

if search_query.isdigit(): # check is digit
    queryset = Book.objects.filter(Q(request_number__icontains=search_query)).distinct()
    return queryset
elif ... : # another check
...
else:
    return 'query is erroneous'
```